# Python Medians of List

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program where you select say median for the option, next could I make it ask you to put in your list and say ("Ex: 10,40,30") and then make it take each item before the "," and append it to a list, then make it take out the ",". Any ideas how I could do this?

This is all I got so far

```
option5=(["1. Median", "2. Average", "3. Mean", "4. Mode"])
for items in option5:
    print (items)
    print ("")
choice5=input("Choose another option: ")
while choice5 not in ("1234"):
    choice5=input("Choose another option: ")
print("")
if choice5 == "1":
    print("Please put your list of numbers like the example below.")
    print("Ex: 10,20,30")
    print("")
    median=input("List: ")
```

Comment: Have a look at the `Counter` [collection](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want: `median_list = median.split(",")`.

[Here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is the documentation for the string method split.

I am presuming that the input maps to output like so:

`1,2,3,4,5` -> `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]`

Another way you could do it that would be more flexible and catch incorrect input like those in your comment is using [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) (don't use the regular `eval` as it is unsafe).

Example:

```
from ast import literal_eval

try:
    median_list = list(literal_eval(median))
except SyntaxError:
    print("Invalid data was entered!")
```

Comment: Thanks man :) Do you have any idea how I would validate that it is listed in that way? For example what if they input "50 70 40 30" without the "," than it wouldn't work so I could I do a while statement to validate that they put it in a certain way? Would I do something like while median not in ",": ??

Comment: You could try and do something like that, but my edit provides a more general answer.

Comment: Thanks man :) But the only problem with this is that it says int object is not iterable. Any ideas? I think the problem is that it says Except SyntaxError, but what if theres a TypeError?

Comment: @user2812028 The second code works fine for me if you put the `try... except...` just below and with `try` at the same indentation as the last line of your program.

Comment: I changed it from SyntaxError to TypeError and it worked. :) Thanks man!